# GNUMake link step not work for certain libraries

Tags: linker, gnu-make, gnu, ld

I can't figure out why my binary does not link with certain libraries in the **GNUMake** file I wrote.  I have:

```
LDLIBRARIES += -L/ms/dist/msjava/PROJ/sunjdk/1.6.0_31/.exec/amd64.linux.2.4.glibc.2.3/jre/lib/amd64/
LDLIBRARIES += -L/ms/dist/msjava/PROJ/sunjdk/1.6.0_31/.exec/amd64.linux.2.4.glibc.2.3/jre/lib/amd64/sever
LDLIBRARIES += -L/ms/dist/msjava/PROJ/sunjdk/1.6.0_31/.exec/amd64.linux.2.4.glibc.2.3/jre/lib/amd64/xawt
LDLIBRARIES += -lmlib_image -lfontmanager -lawt -lmawt
LDLIBRARIES += -ljvm -lverify -lzip -ljava`
```

The binary I get when I run the **ldd** command on it I don't see the files above being linked properly even though they are in the path specified above /ms/dist/msjava/PROJ/sunjdk/1.6.0_31/.exec/amd64.linux.2.4.glibc.2.3/jre/lib/amd64/
The **ldd** command on the resulting binary gives me:

```
libmlib_image.so => not found
libfontmanager.so => not found
libawt.so => not found
libjvm.so => not found
libverify.so =t found
libzip.so =t found
libjava.so => not found
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your `Makefile`. The first one is that you repeat yourself (a lot). In programming, this is generally considered a [bad practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

You can fix this with e.g.

```
JRELIB = /ms/dist/msjava/PROJ/sunjdk/1.6.0_31/.exec/amd64.linux.2.4.glibc.2.3/jre/lib/amd64
LDLIBRARIES += -L${JRELIB} -L${JRELIB}/server -L${JRELIB}/xawt
```

The second problem is that you don't understand the difference between static linking and runtime linking.

When you run `make`, you perform static (build-time) link, which *succeeds*.

When you run `ldd`, you perform runtime link (which fails to find required libraries).

To make runtime link succeed, you need to tell *runtime* linker where the libraries are to be found (the `-L...` flag tells only the *static* linker where to find the libraries). You do that with `-Wl,-rpath=...` flag:

```
LDLIBRARIES += -Wl,-rpath=${JRELIB}:${JRELIB}/server:${JRELIB}/xawt
```

Comment: Yes the problem was actually with the RPATH thanks a lot.